# WPF Textbox Adorner

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, adorner

I have added an Adorner to a Textbox in order to highlight unknown words for custom spellcheck. The adorner works great and the words are being highlighted (underlined).

The issue I need help with is now that the adorner is in place, I can no longer select words in the textbox (I want to be able to highlight a word and then right click and 'Add to dictionary'.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Do I have to do something to the textbox or is this going to be the responsibility of the adorner now?

Comment: Because your adorner is only responsible to render visual feedback you can safely disable hit testing by setting UIElement.IsHitTestVisible on the Adorner instance to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by BionicCode, setting IsHitTestVisible to false resolved the issue here.